# C++ How to define const reference in a multiple declarator in a single definition?

Tags: c++, c++11

Basic form:

```
1. int x = 1, &r = x; -> good    
2. int x = 1;    
   const int &r = x; -> good
3. int x = 1;
   int const &r = x; -> good
4. int x, const int &r = x; -> failed
5. int x, const &r = x; -> failed
```

Questions:
1) What's different between:

```
const int &r = x and
int const &r = x
```

Seems no difference.

2) How do you write a const reference together with other int declarator using single definition as in 4) and 5)

Comment: Upvoted because this is the kind of fundamental question that one learns from. I learned (was forced to think of) another good reason why single declarator declarations are the norm in C++. Namely, the multiple declarator declarations don't support the full range of type variations.

Comment: Downvoted because it is two questions in one. One question per question please.

Comment: Thanks everyone! All are correct. Unfortunately i can only mark one as solution. Wish stackoverflow allows marking of multiple answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between `const int &r = x` and `int const &r = x`.

What you're trying to do isn't possible. A declaration consists of:

1. A *decl-specifier-seq,* which is a sequence of *decl-specifiers* such as `int` and `const`. In most cases, the order of *decl-specifiers* in a *decl-specifier-seq* is immaterial.
2. An *init-declarator-list,* which is (unsurprisingly) a list of *init-declarators*. An *init-declarator* can be something like `x` or `&r = x`.

The declaration is interpreted by separately combining **each** *init-declarator* with **every** *decl-specifier*. Therefore, all entities declared within a single declaration have a common *decl-specifier-seq*. Since `const` is a *decl-specifier* rather than part of a declarator, you can't have it apply to only one of the declarators in a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Re question (1),

> **”** What's different between:
>
> ```
> const int &r = x and
> int const &r = x
> ```

they're the same.

The problem is that `const` belongs syntactically with a type or a `*` or function head directly on its left (and recursively the same for formal function argument types), except the special rule that for the declaration's basic type you can write `const T` instead of `T const`. So the `const` after a comma is syntactically in free air, not connected to anything. And there is no way to pick up the "current type" or introduce some new basic type.

So, re question (2),

> **”** How do you write a const reference together with other int declarator using single definition as in [examples with multiple declarators in the same declaration]?

you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can't declare two different types in one statement, e.g.

```
int x, float y;
```

you can't declare:

```
int x, const int y;
```

on a single statement because `int` and `const int` are different types to the compiler.